# Azure web job .net core Disable attribute app setting does not work

Tags: .net-core, azure-webjobs

Documentation for .net core web jobs suggests that this:

[Disable("messages.disabled")]
public async Task ExecuteAsync(..

should lookup "messages.disabled" in the configuration file and, if set to 1 or True (case insensitive) then it will not run the webjob. This does not appear to be the case.

My app settings are:

```js
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "messages.disabled": "true"
    {
}
```

but this appears to be ignored and my webjob runs regardless. I've tried "true", "True", "1" and placing the setting in the root of the JSON app setting file.

The code compiles file but does not appear to work as expected. I'm using .net core 2.1, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.14

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you solve it with my answer?

Comment: @GeorgeChen FYI: Your answer is for an Azure Function whereas my question was about an Azure Webjob. What I have discovered though is if I place the disable switch in the root of the appsetting.json file as per your example then this appears to work but if it goes in appsetting.development.json it does not - even though all other development settings are picked up. It appears that the disable attribute is not respecting the appsetting hierarchy

Comment: Check my solution, it's just a console it's webjob and this setting could work for both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Working on some suggestions by @GeorgeChen I think there is a bug in the Disable handling for azure web jobs.

If you add the disable attribute to anything other than appSettings.json then it is ignored. This is impractical as, in the majority of case, you do not want to publish these settings to Azure which invariably appSettings.json is - they are more useful when running locally/debugging so you can turn off message handlers for those subscriptions you are not interested in.

A workaround that appears to work is in your webjob program.cs/startup routine, build your IConfigurationRoot as usual. Typically, this build will pull in from appSettings.config, appSettings.Development.config and appSettings.local.config and merge the results.

You can then pull out of this the disable settings you need from the appropriate level for you environment.

Next, set an Environment variable. This then appears to be picked up by the disable attribute.

```
var environment = GetEnvironment();

var cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("messages.examplex.disabled", cfg.GetValue<string>("messages.examplex.disabled"));
```

The Web job method signature:

```
[Disable("messages.examplex.disabled")]
public async Task ExecuteAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("examplex", "subscribertest")]Message msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly about the **Disable** attribute, after using it in the function method, you should set the app setting in the `appsettings.json` file, the format would be like below. And remember set the `CopyToOutputDirectory` property to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image]

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "storage account connection string",
  "Disable": true

}
```

[image]

The other thing is you could use another setting to disable function. You could set `"AzureWebJobs.YourFunctionName.Disabled": "true"` to disable your function.

[image]